# MYSQL How do I select data from one table only where column values from that table match the column values of another table?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two tables.  I want to get the UIDs from table 1 where the subject columns from both tables match.

```
Table 1              

UID   SubjectA           
1     Cows           
2     Chickens       
3     Mice           
4     Rabbits        
5     Cows           

Table 2

Name    SubjectB 
A       Cows
B       Cows
C       Cows
D       Cows
E       Mice
```

**Expected Result***

Fetch UIDs: 1, 3, 5.

I don't quite understand joins and unions.  Both seem to combine two tables.  What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this...

First, I'd suggest using `exists`:

```
SELECT
    UID
FROM
    Table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table2
    WHERE SubjectB = SubjectA
)
```

Or, you can use a `join` and `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    UID
FROM
    Table1 JOIN
    Table2 ON SubjectB = SubjectA
```

Lastly, you can use `in`:

```
SELECT
    UID
FROM
    Table1
WHERE SubjectA IN (
    SELECT SubjectB
    FROM Table2
)
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy response!  may i ask what the "SELECT 1" line means? How would the function change if there were a different number say 2 or 3?

Comment: @tjones `exists` will return true if a row is returned... since it doesn't matter what value is in the row that is returned, hard-coding a value is an optimization to keep SQL from having to pull an actual value from the table.  it doesn't matter what value is hard-coded... it could be `2`, `3`, or `'potato'`...

Comment: Check the EXPLAIN plans but I am sure you will find the INNER JOIN is significantly faster than the correlated sub-query used in the EXISTS version.

Comment: @tjones The 1 in `SELECT 1` has no meaning whatsoever. You can use `SELECT NULL`, `SELECT *` or anything you want as [MySQL disregards the SELECT list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) in these queries.